# Relevance sorting for shop products in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

Assume we have an online shop.

1. The **products table** contains a `ReleaseDate` and `IsPublished` value.
2. The **orders table** contains a `CreatedDate` and `OrderItems` (containing `ProductId` and `Count`)
3. The **discounts table** contains a `ProductId` and eventually a more complex product query as well as the discount itself.

My goal is to create a product listing with facets for product properties and **relevance sorting**.
Facets in RavenDB are awesome, no problem here.
My problem is the sorting.

The idea is the following:
Products are sorted by multiple criteria (*release date*, *sold units* and *is on sale*). The product gets 0 to 100 points for each criteria. 0 points for the minimum value and 100 points for the maximum value. Each criteria has a weight. Eventually for release date that's 50% weight, for sold units 20%, and on sale 30%.

That results in the following formula (pseudo code):

```
product.relevance = 
(50 * (product.releaseDate - minReleaseDate) / (maxReleaseDate - minReleaseDate)) +
(20 * (product.soldUnits - minSoldUnits) / (maxSoldUnits - minSoldUnits)) +
(30 * (product.isOnSale ? 1 : 0))
```

I do already have an index which contains the products with their release dates and soldUnits. Discounts are still a problem but not part of this question. I do also have access to the min/max values for my criteria via facets (minOn/maxOn).

---

**My question**:

What is the best option to solve this problem? I have thought about creating a JavaScript index, which contains a function ("The Script") for the relevance calculation. But how do I get the min/max values within the index? I will probably need one index for the values (release date, sold units) and another one for the relevance, right? I guess that would make it harder to query the data.
I have also found custom collectors for Lucene, which is probably the functionality I need? Yet I couldn't find anything related in RavenDB *(currently using v5.1)*.

Is the way I am trying to solve this problem too complex?